# What is $\mathrm{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}}^1 (\mathbb{Z}[[ t ]] , \mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I want to compute  $\mathrm{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}}^1 (\mathbb{Z}[[ t ]] , \mathbb{Z})$. By a classical result of [Baer](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00229-005-0608-8.pdf), the formal power series group $\mathbb{Z}[[ t ]]$ is not projective, so at first glance I do not have any reason to assume that the Ext group should vanish.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: As an abelian group, $\mathbb Z[[t]]$ is $\mathbb{Z^N}$ so you can try to use that and the usual injective resolution of $\mathbb Z$ to compute the $\mathrm{Ext}$